# Firefox CSS transitions with body overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, transition

CSS transitions stop working in FireFox when adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<body>` tag via JavaScript. (At least on FF32.0.3 running on OSX10.9.5)

When adding the overflow via JavaScript, the CSS transitions do not fire:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rc7kk28/2/

Without adding the overflow the CSS transitions work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rc7kk28/3/

How can I get the first example to work? I need to maintain the `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rc7kk28/4/

- Applies `overflow: hidden` rule immediately.
- Introduces a small delay via `setTimeout`.
- After delay adds classes that trigger the CSS transitions.